# Converting a WordPress site into a PWA

Tags: android, installation, progressive-web-apps, offlineapps, trusted-web-activity

I have a WordPress website and I am transforming this website to a PWA with the help of a plugin.

The PWA is working as expected: notifications, working without internet …

I have also followed this tutorial completely:

https://css-tricks.com/how-to-get-a-progressive-web-app-into-the-google-play-store/

At the end, I have an Android launcher.

The new app is doing this:

1. If the browser is not set by default, it will ask the user to choose a browser.
2. I have an URL bar at the top of the app.
3. The app is not working without internet.

How can I fix all those points?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. If the browser is not set by default, it will ask the user to choose a browser

Can't get this one, every mobile phone already do that by default, I think.

> 2. I have an URL bar on top of the app

Check if you have included the tag:

```
"display": "standalone"
```

on the `manifest.json` file

> 3. the app is not working without internet.

Check your `service-worker.js` file to see the resources needed to provide an offline experience are effectively cached. One can use [this nice tool](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/) from Google to define routes policy easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [Helpful tool](https://appmaker.xyz/pwa-to-apk/).

Answer (score 0):

## Not installed yet

A URL bar being still visible at the top is indicative that the web page has **not** been installed yet as a PWA on your device. Choose `Install` from the tab menu or click on a `[↓]` icon next to the URL bar.

This will most probably also solve your other problems.